# Rails 5 validar CPF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validação

Olá, sou iniciante em RoR. Tenho um formulário com campo para CPF e preciso validar se é válido ou não antes de salvar o registro.

Tentei diferentes gems como: gem'cpf_cnpj', gem 'brcpfcnpj' e 'validates_cpf_cnpj', mas seguindo o readme no github, todas deram algum tipo de erro, talvez pela compatibilidade do ruby ou rails.

Minha última tentativa foi utilizar um código em ruby e criar um custom validate, mas também não obtive sucesso.

Alguém tem alguma solução utilizando Rails 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a gem: [CPF/CNPJ](https://github.com/fnando/cpf_cnpj)

Atente-se para o uso do `require`

Utilizei ela para testar com o `Rails 5.0.6` e  `ruby 2.3.1p112`

A mesma funcionou perfeitamente, pode ser utilizadas outra gems  também.

Você pode usar os recursos de `callback` e fazer uma validação antes de salvar os dados `before_save`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Também é possível utilizar a solução desse link: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/validacao-de-cnpj-com-ruby

Comment: Valeu! Estranho que a primeira vez que tentei usar esta gem deu erro exatamente no require... mas agora deu certo!